# Not exiting from shell script

Tags: shell

I am trying to stop processing a shell script with an IF condition.

```
output7=${output7##*[[:space:]]}

if [[ $output4 -gt 0 && $output5 -gt 0 && $output6 -gt 0 && $output7 -gt 0 ]]
then echo 'Success'
else echo 'Failure'|| exit 0
fi

echo 'Process Completed'
```

It is printing the following message but the next statement is also being executed. The output is:

```
Failure
Process Completed
```

Can anyone pls tell me why it is not exiting the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are saying that "if `echo 'Failure'` *fails*, then `exit 0`", which is not what you want. You'll want

```
echo 'Failure'
exit 1
```

instead. Idiomatic Bash style for the whole section would be:

```
if [[ $output4 -gt 0 ]] && [[ $output5 -gt 0 ]] && [[ $output6 -gt 0 ]] && [[ $output7 -gt 0 ]]
then
    echo 'Success'
else
    echo 'Failure'
    exit 1
fi
```